# How to overwrite files in rails using custom generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, generator

I have a custom generator called Datatable, and the file structure is like this :

```
 lib/generators/datatable/templates
 lib/generators/datatable/templates/datatables.rb
/lib/generators/datatable/datatable_generator.rb
```

These are my folder structure and my datatable_generator.rb contain :

```
 class DatatableGenerator < ::Rails::Generators::Base
  desc 'Creates a *_datatable model in the app/datatables directory.'
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  # argument :name, :type => :string
   argument :name, :type => :string
   argument :name1, type: :array, default: [], banner: "action"
  def generate_datatable
    file_prefix = set_filename(name)
    @datatable_name = set_datatable_name(name)
    template 'datatable.rb', File.join(
      'app/datatables', "#{file_prefix}_datatable.rb"
    )
  copy_file "stylesheet.css", "public/stylesheets/#{file_name}.css"
  template  "layout.html.erb", "app/views/#{file_name}s/index.html.erb"
  end

  private
 def file_name
   name.underscore
 end
  def set_filename(name)
    name.include?('_') ? name : name.to_s.underscore
  end

  def set_datatable_name(name)
    name.include?('_') ? build_name(name) : capitalize(name)
  end

  def build_name(name)
    pieces = name.split('_')
    pieces.map(&:titleize).join
  end

  def capitalize(name)
    return name if name[0] == name[0].upcase
    name.capitalize
  end
end
```

I am trying to find a way by which I need to change the index action of a controller for example I am generating datatable for demo for that I will run this command generate datatable Demo cbc cbdd cbse here demo is a scaffold and in its index action  I need to override only index action where I want this :

```
  def index
@dis_additive_frequencies = DisAdditiveFrequency.all
 end
```

to be like this :

```
def index
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render    json:DisAdditiveFrequencieDatatable.new(view_context) }
 end
 end
```

Is there any method by which I can only edit index action of certain file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thor functions like gsub_file or insert_into_file you can check the documentation of thor : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor%2FActions%3Agsub_file

I think you want to replace the previous index action and you want to replace it with new one for that you can use this code :

```
 # Start ---this logic is to comment default index action querly example @ankurs = Ankur.all
   path = "app/controllers/#{file_name}s_controller.rb"
   line = "@#{file_name}s = #{@datatable_name}.all"
   gsub_file(path, /^(\s*)([^#|\n]*#{line})/, '\1# \2', *args)
   # End ---this logic is to comment default index action querly example @ankurs = Ankur.all

 # Start ---this logic is to append content in index action
  content = "
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json:#{@datatable_name}Datatable.new(view_context) }
    end"
  insert_into_file path, content, :after => "@#{file_name}s = #{@datatable_name}.all\n"
  end
 # Start ---this logic is to append content in index action
```

This will comment the code which you want to replace and new one will be added below .